# Calling Marketing Cloud APIs from C# via FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk, c#, oauth

In am trying to get an access token to call Salesforce Marketing Api through FuelSDK the code is:

```
    NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
    parameters.Add("clientId", "myclientidvalugoeshere");
    parameters.Add("clientSecret", "myclientsecretvaluegoeshere");
    parameters.Add("authEndPoint", "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken");

    var client = new ETClient(parameters);           

    ETFolder folder = new ETFolder();
    folder.AuthStub = client;            
   
    var response = folder.Get();
    return response.Message;
```

But it's returning:
**System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.**
I am not really sure if I am doing it the right way.

What I really want to do is to connect to Salesforce Marketing cloud through FuelSDK C#, using Oauth authentication to get access token for the user and call the resources needed. All the resources I have gotten online hasn't really helped. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp

Comment: Yes I used it initially in my implementation but still getting the same error. Thanks